# What's making this algorithm crash?

Tags: c++, file, crash, fread

before showing exactly the code, let me explain the problem in detail. 
I need to create 2 dat files with some data about hotels in them. One of the files contains the following info: Name of the province the hotel is in (string of 16), category of the hotel (int), code of the hotel (int), name of the hotel (string of 30), amount of rooms (int), and amount of currently reserved rooms (int). The second dat file contains the code of hotels that are being eliminated from the list. The final part of the test is to create a file that has all of the information of the remaining hotels. Since, in theory, i already have the info if the 2 first dat files, i just wrote something simple. Noteworthy to mention is that i have to use dev c++ 4.9.9.2:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <fstream>
#include <string.h>
#include <cstdio>

using namespace std;


struct rhot
{      
   char provincia[16];
   int categoria;
   int chot;
   char nombrehotel[30];
   int canthabitaciones;
   int habitreservadas;
};

int main()
{
rhot hot1 =
{    
 "Còrdoba",
 4,
 1,
 "La pachamama",
 100,
 49
 };
rhot hot2 =
{    
 "Salta",
 3,
 2,
 "Puntoblanco",
 60,
 13
 };
rhot hot3 =
{    
 "Catamarca",
 4,
 3,
 "Jaguar Resort",
 250,
 197
 };
rhot hot4 =
{    
 "Chubut",
 6,
 4,
 "Llao Llao",
 300,
 299
 };
rhot hot5 =
{    
 "La pampa",
 2,
 5,
 "Gaunchito",
 40,
 20
 };
rhot hot6 =
{    
 "Mendoza",
 3,
 6,
 "Queseyo",
 60,
 13
 };


FILE* f1;
 f1 = fopen("Arhot.dat", "w");

fwrite(&hot1,sizeof(hot1),1,f1); 
fwrite(&hot2,sizeof(hot2),1,f1); 
fwrite(&hot3,sizeof(hot3),1,f1); 
fwrite(&hot4,sizeof(hot4),1,f1); 
fwrite(&hot5,sizeof(hot5),1,f1); 
fwrite(&hot6,sizeof(hot6),1,f1); 

fclose(f1);  

system("PAUSE");
return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

And the second one:

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <cmath>
 #include <fstream>
 #include <string.h>
 #include <cstdio>

using namespace std;


struct Rbaja
{      
   int Cbajas;
 };

int main()
{
Rbaja Baja1 =
{    
 1
 };
Rbaja Baja2 =
{    
 5
 };



FILE* f1;
f1 = fopen("Arbaj.dat", "w");

fwrite(&Baja1,sizeof(Baja1),1,f1); 
fwrite(&Baja2,sizeof(Baja2),1,f1); 


fclose(f1);  

system("PAUSE");
return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

(i also want to mention that i dont know what libraries i really need for this, i tried deleting each one of them and running the programs and it isnt giving me any errors even when it has no libraries, so just because i dont know what to do i left them all there)

And now i'm trying to make this work. I need to read the 2 files created above, and try to create one based on what i said at the start. However i barely wrote an fread function and whenever i compile and run it it crashes

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <fstream>
#include <string.h>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>


using namespace std;
 FILE* fileArhot;
 FILE* fileArbaj;
 FILE* fileAract;

struct rhot
{      
       char provincia[16];
       int catergoria;
       int chot;
       char nombrehotel[30];
       int cantahibaticones;
       int habitreservadas;
};

struct rbaja
{      
       int Cbajas;
};

struct rhotact
{      
       char provincia[16];
       int catergoria;
       int chot;
       char nombrehotel[30];
       int cantahibaticones;
       int habitreservadas;
};

int main()
{
fileArhot =fopen("Arhot.dat","r");
fileArbaj =fopen("Arbaj.dat","r");
fileAract =fopen("Aract.dat","w");

fread(&fileArhot,sizeof(rhot),1,fileArhot);
fread(&fileArbaj,sizeof(rbaja),1,fileArbaj);


 fclose(fileArhot);
 fclose(fileArbaj);
 fclose(fileAract); 
 system("PAUSE");
 return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Whenever i try to run this, the program crashes. I think its because its doing an infinite loop or something,but i have no idea. I included the creation code of the 2 dat files because i might have created them wrong.

Either way, i would like some help :D
(also sorry if the text is in spanish, i'm from argentina and well i need to do the code with spanish words.)

Comment: 1. Why don't you post the text of the input files, rather than the code you used to create them? 2. Have you tried using a debugger to step through the code and see what line it is crashing on?

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Answer (score 2):

You're passing the wrong arguments to `fread`;

```
fread(&fileArhot,sizeof(rhot),1,fileArhot);
```

overwrites `fileArhot`, and is undefined.

You also forgot to declare the variables you intend to read into.

It should be

```
rhot an_rhot; // or whatever you want to name it
fread(&an_rhot, sizeof(rhot), 1, fileArhot);
```

or the slightly safer

```
fread(&an_rhot, sizeof(an_rhot), 1, fileArhot);
```

and similar for the other read.

You should also add some checking to verify that you've opened, read, and written the files successfully.

I would recommend that you look at using C++ I/O instead of the C libraries, as it's much safer.

Comment: `fread(&rhot,sizeof(rhot),1,fileArhot);
     fread(&rbaja,sizeof(rbaja),1,fileArbaj); `                                                   This reads me an error with the "," (expected primary expresion before "," token)

Comment: @Loquen I misread and thought that `rhot` was a variable and not a type. I updated the answer. (You did this correctly in both the other programs, by the way.)